# Count unique IDs for each group within x days

Tags: r, data.table

This is a follow-up question to one I already posted here: [Count occurrence of IDs within the last x days in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66573334/count-occurrence-of-ids-within-the-last-x-days-in-r)

I'm trying to do another rolling count. I have the following data:

```
date = c("2014-04-01", "2014-04-12", "2014-04-07", "2014-05-03", "2014-04-14", "2014-05-04", "2014-03-31", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-23", "2014-04-01")
group = c("G","G","F","G","E","E","H","H","H","A")
ID = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1)
```

```
    group       date ID
 1:     G 2014-04-01  2
 2:     G 2014-04-12  3
 3:     F 2014-04-07  4
 4:     G 2014-05-03  2
 5:     E 2014-04-14  3
 6:     E 2014-05-04  1
 7:     H 2014-03-31  2
 8:     H 2014-04-18  4
 9:     H 2014-04-23  2
10:     A 2014-04-01  1
```

For each `group`, I would like to count the number of unique `ID` within the past 30 days of the current `date`. The desired count column would look like this:

```
    group       date ID  count
 1:     G 2014-04-01  2      1
 2:     G 2014-04-12  3      2
 3:     F 2014-04-07  4      1
 4:     G 2014-05-03  1      2
 5:     E 2014-04-14  3      1
 6:     E 2014-05-04  1      2
 7:     H 2014-03-31  2      1
 8:     H 2014-04-18  4      2
 9:     H 2014-04-23  2      3
10:     A 2014-04-01  1      1
```

In my previous thread, a solution by @ThomasIsCoding was provided. I tried to modify his code to perform the task I am now trying to do by doing the following:

```
dt[date <= first(date) + 30, date := as.Date(date)][, count := uniqueN(ID), group]
    group       date ID count
 1:     G 2014-04-01  2     2
 2:     G 2014-04-12  3     2
 3:     F 2014-04-07  4     1
 4:     G 2014-05-03  2     2
 5:     E 2014-04-14  3     2
 6:     E 2014-05-04  1     2
 7:     H 2014-03-31  2     2
 8:     H 2014-04-18  4     2
 9:     H 2014-04-23  2     2
10:     A 2014-04-01  1     1
```

But it doesn't seem to take into account the time range condition. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using non-equi join:

```
DT[, onemthago := date - 30L]    
DT[, count := 
    DT[.SD, on=.(group, date>=onemthago, date<=date),
        by=.EACHI, length(unique(ID))]$V1
]
```

output:

```
    group       date ID  onemthago count
 1:     G 2014-04-01  2 2014-03-02     1
 2:     G 2014-04-12  3 2014-03-13     2
 3:     F 2014-04-07  4 2014-03-08     1
 4:     G 2014-05-03  2 2014-04-03     2
 5:     E 2014-04-14  3 2014-03-15     1
 6:     E 2014-05-04  1 2014-04-04     2
 7:     H 2014-03-31  2 2014-03-01     1
 8:     H 2014-04-18  4 2014-03-19     2
 9:     H 2014-04-23  2 2014-03-24     2
10:     A 2014-04-01  1 2014-03-02     1
```

data:

```
date = as.Date(c("2014-04-01", "2014-04-12", "2014-04-07", "2014-05-03", "2014-04-14", "2014-05-04", "2014-03-31", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-23", "2014-04-01"))
group = c("G","G","F","G","E","E","H","H","H","A")
ID = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1)
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(group, date, ID)
```

---

edit to address comment on multiple lookback periods. You can try something like:

```
for (x in c(30L, 90L)) {
    DT[, daysago := date - x]
    
    DT[, paste0("count", x) := 
        .SD[.SD, on=.(group, date>=daysago, date<=date),
            by=.EACHI, length(unique(ID))]$V1
    ][]
}
DT
```

Answer (score 1):

See how well this proposed solution works for your case.

```r
date = c("2014-04-01", "2014-04-12", "2014-04-07", "2014-05-03", "2014-04-14", "2014-05-04", "2014-03-31", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-23", "2014-04-01")
group = c("G","G","F","G","E","E","H","H","H","A")
ID = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1)

dt <- data.table( date=as.Date(date), group, ID )
setkey( dt, group, date )
calc.id <- function(ID,date) {
    ## there is always going to be at least 1
    id.count <- 1
    if( length(ID) > 1 ) {
        v <- sapply( 2:length(ID), function(i) {
            j <- date[ 1:i ] >= date[i] - 30
            uniqueN( ID[j] )
        })
        id.count <- c( id.count, v )
    }
    return( id.count )
}
dt[ , count := calc.id(ID,date), by=group ]

dt
```

I didn't find another way than to use sapply for the rolling calculation. I doubt it will outperform the solution above.

It produces this:

```
          date group ID count
 1: 2014-04-01     A  1     1
 2: 2014-04-14     E  3     1
 3: 2014-05-04     E  1     2
 4: 2014-04-07     F  4     1
 5: 2014-04-01     G  2     1
 6: 2014-04-12     G  3     2
 7: 2014-05-03     G  2     2
 8: 2014-03-31     H  2     1
 9: 2014-04-18     H  4     2
10: 2014-04-23     H  2     2
```

Comment: Hello Sirius! Thanks for the reply. The few problems here is that on row 3, it says NA but i would like the count to say 2 since group E has had two unique IDS within the 30 days including the current date, which are (ID = 3 and ID = 1). For row 7, I would like that count to be 2, and for row 8, I would like that count to be 1.

Comment: I updated with a statement to update each group with non-NA values from that group. 
(there might be more slick ways, na.omit would likely do since you are guaranteed to have a non-NA in there)

Comment: (you can of course chain those statements per the usual data.table way)

Comment: Thanks Sirius! Only problem is that row 3 should have a count of 2. Since 30 days prior to the current date and including the current date, group E as had two unique IDs, which are 3 and 1. Row 8 should have a count of 1 since it has only seen that unique ID once.

Comment: I have misunderstood you from the beginning. For fast solution to a data.table with millions of rows.. options are more limited. I'll see what I can come up wtih.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your feedback and time.

Comment: is the original order important, or should rows be sorted by date within each group?

Comment: The original order is not important. The rows can be sorted by date within each group!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229918/discussion-between-sirius-and-statman123).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly one alternative way within the tidyverse would be this:

```
library(tidyverse)

tb <- dplyr::tibble(date = c("2014-04-01", "2014-04-12", "2014-04-07", "2014-05-03", "2014-04-14", "2014-05-04", "2014-03-31", "2014-04-18", "2014-04-23", "2014-04-01"),
                    group = c("G","G","F","G","E","E","H","H","H","A"),
                    ID = c(2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1))

tb %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), date)) < 31) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(ID) %>% 
  dplyr::count(group) %>% 
  dplyr::right_join(tb) %>% 
  dplyr::select(group, date, ID, Count = n)

   group date          ID Count
    <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <int>
 1 A     2014-04-01     1     1
 2 E     2014-04-14     3     2
 3 E     2014-05-04     1     2
 4 F     2014-04-07     4     1
 5 G     2014-04-01     2     2
 6 G     2014-04-12     3     2
 7 G     2014-05-03     2     2
 8 H     2014-03-31     2     2
 9 H     2014-04-18     4     2
10 H     2014-04-23     2     2
```

for the rolling window type of function this should be a solution:

```
tb %>% 
  dplyr::full_join(tb, by = "group") %>% 
  dplyr::filter(as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(date.x), as.Date(date.y), units = "days")) >= 0 & as.numeric(difftime(date.x, date.y, units = "days")) < 31) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(group, date.x, ID.y) %>% 
  dplyr::count(group, date.x) %>% 
  # you might want to cut the pipe here and look at the result (do not forget to delete the %>% in the line above when removing the part below
  dplyr::right_join(tb, by = c("group", "date.x" = "date")) %>% 
  dplyr::select(group, date = date.x, ID, count = n)

   group date          ID count
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl> <int>
 1 A     2014-04-01     1     1
 2 E     2014-04-14     3     1
 3 E     2014-05-04     1     2
 4 F     2014-04-07     4     1
 5 G     2014-04-01     2     1
 6 G     2014-04-12     3     2
 7 G     2014-05-03     2     2
 8 H     2014-03-31     2     1
 9 H     2014-04-18     4     2
10 H     2014-04-23     2     2
```

Comment: Hi @DPH, thanks for the suggestion. My only concern is that I would like to keep the length of column to be equal to the rows on my original table. So, at the current date, it looks at how many unique IDs has occurred within 30 days, and it does this for each group.

Comment: ok, I will alter my code acordingly... Just have to join by on the original data... one minute please

Comment: Hello @DPH, that is super close to the solution I am looking for, but for the first date of each group, it should have a count of 1 since that is the first unique ID at that current date. For example, row 5 should have a count of 1 because it has only seen one unique ID.

Comment: @statman123 if i understand you correctly you are looking for a window type of function - like 30 back from each date in the data.frame (not only 30 days back from the current date)?

Comment: yes that is correct! Sorry I should have made that more clear.

Comment: @statman123 I altered my answer with a second part for the rolling sum... I work it with a full join (just like you would use in SQL language) and then filter the data acording to the allowed limits (0 to 30 days)

Comment: Thanks for the help! You provided some very helpful code. I'm hoping to get something similar with ```data.table``` as my entire dataset contains millions of rows, so I'm worried about the running time by using ```dplyr```. I'm thinking I could use your time condition code to get the desired count output with a ```data.table``` solution. Anyways, thank you so much for your time and solution :)